# hostapd don't start at boot

Tags: boot, access-point, hostapd

I spend the whole day to understand how to use the Raspberry (1 B+) as access point with the awus036nha with scratch, following this guide, [Setting up a Raspberry Pi as an access point in a standalone network (NAT)](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/access-point.md), but can't start `hostapd` after boot, `wpa_supplicant` is disabled:

```
sudo nano /etc/dhcpcd.conf  
.(blablabla)
.
.
# fallback to static profile on eth0
#interface eth0
#fallback static_eth0
interface wlan0
static ip_address=192.168.2.1/24
nohook wpa_supplicant
```

I have noticed that I need to kill `hostapd` after boot with

```
sudo killall hostapd ,
```

and then restart again to make it works with

```
 sudo hostapd /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf
```

and with this, everything  works...
but the auto start not, I've already added at `/etc/default/hostapd`

```
DAEMON_CONF="/etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf"
```

and did an

```
 sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Any suggestion?

**EDIT:** doing

```
sudo systemctl enable hostapd


pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo systemctl status hostapd
hostapd.service - LSB: Advanced IEEE 802.11 management d
Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/hostapd; generated; vendor 
Active: active (running) since Sun 2018-08-05 14:34:26 
Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
Process: 328 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/hostapd start (code=e
CGroup: /system.slice/hostapd.service
└─466 /usr/sbin/hostapd -B -P /run/hostapd.pid 

ago 05 14:34:18 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Adva
ago 05 14:34:26 raspberrypi hostapd[328]: Starting advance
ago 05 14:34:26 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started LSB: Advan
lines 1-11/11 (END)...skipping...
● hostapd.service - LSB: Advanced IEEE 802.11 management daemon

Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/hostapd; generated; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: active (running) since Sun 2018-08-05 14:34:26 CEST; 2min 28s ago
Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
Process: 328 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/hostapd start (code=exited, 
status=0/SUCCESS)
CGroup: /system.slice/hostapd.service
       └─466 /usr/sbin/hostapd -B -P /run/hostapd.pid 
/etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf
ago 05 14:34:18 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Advanced IEEE 802.11 m 
management daemon...
ago 05 14:34:26 raspberrypi hostapd[328]: Starting advanced IEEE 802.11 
management: hostapd.
ago 05 14:34:26 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started LSB: Advanced IEEE 802.11 
management daemon.
```

**EDIT2:**

```
sudo nano  /etc/init.d/hostapd

....(blabla)...
PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
DAEMON_SBIN=/usr/sbin/hostapd
DAEMON_DEFS=/etc/default/hostapd
DAEMON_CONF=
NAME=hostapd
...
```

Comment: Did you try 'sudo systemctl enable hostapd'? And check the status with 'sudo systemctl status hostapd'?

Comment: @Dirk thanks for your help, i have update the post with the output ( still not working after reboot)

Comment: AFAICT it's running. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Dirk exacly, but no AP is showing, i need to do a "sudo service hostapd restart" to make it appear.. any suggestion?  could I use some workaround to make it restart automatically? maybe with rc.local?

Comment: rc.local is probably the least reliable of all possible solutions. You have no control over when it runs during startup. I have no idea why it's not working; probably some sort of sequence problem, but wlan0 must be up otherwise I would expect it to fail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've resolved by myself, I have made a script in bash that restart the `hostapd` service with

```
 #!/bin/bash
 service hostapd restart
```

and make it executable with

```
  sudo chmod +x /location/file
```

then used

```
 sudo visudo
```

and make the file executable without asking for password, adding in the file

```
 [your_username] ALL= NOPASSWD: /location/of/file
```

went in

```
  cd /home/pi/.config/autostart
  sudo nano name.desktop
```

and adding in the file

```
 [Desktop Entry]
 Encoding=UTF-8
 Type=Application
 Name=name
 Comment=restart hostapd service
 Exec=sudo lxterminal -e "/location/of/the/file"
```

This file will be executable after the GUI is loaded, and this file will call the bash script in sudo mode, without asking for password, restarting hostapd service after boot... maybe is not the smartest solution but I spent two days on it and didn't found much help.

**EDIT:** My fault, I had edited (following another guide) `/etc/network/interfaces` and my configuration at `/etc/dhcpcd.conf` were not loaded, so I just uncommented the interface configuration and everything worked as expected.

Answer (score 1):

My hostapd2.6 also failed to start on raspbian stretch, just adding it to crontab will works.

```
crontab -e
```

```
@reboot sleep 60 && /usr/sbin/hostapd -B /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf
```

Or the sleep might not be needed in your situation

```
@reboot /usr/sbin/hostapd -B /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf
```

Well I found another solution:
add the following line to the end of **/etc/default/hostapd**

```
DAEMON_CONF="/etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf"
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.  I'm suspicious that hostapd is conflicting or dependent on another process starting up.  It basically causes hostapd to start after the other services.  I'm actually surprised to see all of the symlinks S01 and the lack of a networking symlink but my Linux knowledge is probably a bit dated at this point.  I was expecting something like S03networking and S04sshd.

```
sudo mv /etc/rc5.d/S01hostapd /etc/rc5.d/S02hostapd
```

Note rc5 maps to the runlevel.

```
runlevel 
N 5
```